# Using class methods(class function members) outside the class declaration and method definitions

Tags: c++

I am reading a C++ textbook for teaching myself programming.

Now I have a question with a sentance in the fallowing paragraph

which is underlined in red.

[image]

I don't understand what does that sentance mean.

> Using class methods(class function members) outside the class declaration and method definitions.

How to use class methods(class function members) outside method definitions?

What are special measures?

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "which we'll get to soon"... To me it sounds like the are just wanting to use some vague and big sounding language before telling you that they'll just tell you the details later. Keep reading (or find a different book).

Comment: @user9418 - Do they mean `static` methods? Keep reading and see what the book says!

Comment: "... requires special measures, which we'll get to soon". Turn the page!

Comment: The textbook is "C++ Primer Plus" written by Stephen Prata.

Comment: FInd a [better book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I have "C++ Primer" as well. Most of the time I read "C++ Primer Plus" and reference to "C++ Primer".

Comment: @Phorce - Actually I have read through the whole book. After that I still don't understand what does that sentance mean.

Comment: @user9418 Continue reading.. This should become more clear to you :) + There are good answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think basically it means that in order to use this class method from other code (main method, other class method body, etc) you need additional measures. With this it means basically that you have to make this class visible to the scope where you are trying to use it (in general by including the header where it's defined) so you are able to instance variables/objects of this class and to call its methods on them.

For example, in order to use this class (let's call it foo) from other code you have to do the following:

```
#include "foo.h"

void MyClass::bar()
{
     Foo instanceOfFoo;
     instanceOfFoo.Update();
     ....
}
```

If you need to call the Update() method from the Foo class .cpp file there's no need to create an instance of itself. So you can call its methods with these *additional measures*. So the Foo class methods could call the Update like the following:

```
void Foo::SomeMethod()
{
    Update(); // 
}
```

In fact the above method has a hidden parameted called *this* which refers to the current instance of the Foo class. So the code above is something like:

```
void Foo::SomeMethod(Foo* const this)
{
    this->Update(); // 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means if you use it in some other method of `Stock` you don't need the class scope `Stock::Update()`, for example

```
void Stock::Foo()
{
    // Do stuff

    Update(10.0);   // This is Stock::Update()
}
```

But if you called it in some function outside the method of the `Stock` class, you would need an instance of `Stock` to call the method from, because it is non-`static`.

```
void Bar()
{
    Stock stock;

    // Do stuff

    stock.Update(10.0);    // This will find the Stock:: scope
}
```

This also means that the method `Update` has to be `public` for you to call it in the above example `Bar`. If it were `private`, you could only call the `Update` method from other `Stock` methods.

```
class Stock
{
public:
    void Update(double price);
};
```